# Keep Getting "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed" when saving to the context a second time.

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I keep getting the following error when I am executing my HttpPost form a second time.

```
InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. 

Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
```

My ApplicationDbContext is initialised in my controller as such:

```
public class AssetController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AssetController(
        ApplicationDbContext context,)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

And this is the function in the controller that handles the post and save:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(IFormFile file, AddAssetViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

            var assetOwnership =
                _context.AssetOwnership.SingleOrDefault(o => o.AssetOwnershipId == model.OwnershipId);

            var origin = _context.Location.SingleOrDefault(l => l.LocationId == model.OriginId);

            var currentLocation = _context.Location.SingleOrDefault(l => l.LocationId == model.CurrentLocationId);

            var division = _context.Division.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DivisionId == model.DivisionId);

            var normalAsset = model.NormalAsset == 2;

            var uploadSavePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads\\AssetPictures\\");

            var trackingNumber = GetTrackingNumber(model.OwnershipId, model.DivisionId);

            var asset = new Asset
            {
                TrackingNum = trackingNumber,
                Owner = currentUser,
                Ownership = assetOwnership,
                CurrentLocation = currentLocation,
                Origin = origin,
                ModelName = model.ModelName,
                SerialNum = model.SerialNum,
                Division = division,
                Desc = model.Desc,
                HwOpt = model.HwOpt,
                SwOpt = model.SwOpt,
                Availability = model.Availability,
                Remarks = model.Remarks,
                ReadyToSell = model.ReadyToSell,
                PurchaseDate = model.PurchaseDate,
                PurchasePo = model.PurchasePo,
                NormalAsset = normalAsset,
                MaterialNumber = model.MaterialNum,
                IsTagged = model.IsTagged,
                PurchasePrice = model.PurchasePrice,
                IsDamaged = model.IsDamaged,
                LastCalDate = model.LastCalDate,
                Firmware = model.Firmware,
                EstimatedNextCalDate = model.EstimatedNextCalDate,
                LicenceExpiry = model.LicenceExpiry
            };

            if (file != null)
            {
                var imageName = asset.TrackingNum + ".jpg";

                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var fileStream =
                        new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadSavePath, imageName), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                    asset.AssetPicture = imageName;
                }
            }

            _context.Asset.Add(asset);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
}

}
```

When I am only submitting the form for the first time, everything goes fine, item is saved into the database properly. However, when I try to add a second item, I get the error.
Can anybody help me to fix this?
Error output is saying it fails at

```
Project.Controllers.AssetController+<Add>d__14.MoveNext() in AssetController.cs
+
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Please see [Managing DbContext the right way with Entity Framework 6: an in-depth guide](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/). The simplest solution is to use `using` blocks whenever you require writing or reading from the context and not to store the context in a private variable like `_context`: `using (var context = new DbContext()) { ... }`

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I have mentioned it in the post. " public class AssetController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AssetController(
        ApplicationDbContext context,)
    {
        _context = context;
    } "

Comment: @PrzemysławZalewski Can you guide me through it? How can I make the new DbContext aware of which database to connect to?

Comment: I haven't used multiple databases in EF yet, but the `DbContext` accepts name or connection string so you can pass `"DefaultConnection"` to it's constructor to use the default connection string defined in Web.config: `using (var context = new DbContext("DefaultConnection")) { ... }`. You can also define custom context class like this: `public class UsersContext : DbContext { public UsersContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }   
 public DbSet<User> UserProfiles { get; set; } ... }` and use the specific version then by `using(var context = new UsersContext()) { ... }`.

Comment: Oh no because when I initialise it as var context = new ApplicationDbContext() the application isn't aware of the database provider, do I need to create a new constructor in my ApplicationDbContext? @PrzemysławZalewski

Comment: `using(var context = new ApplicationDbContext()) { }` should do the work but if you want to specify a connection string, you can create another constructor or add an optional parameter:  `public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext { public ApplicationDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString = "DefaultConnection") : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }  }`

Comment: @Lewis: Your problem is probably that `ApplicationDbContext` is registered as a singleton rather a per-request lifetime scope.

Comment: @StephenCleary I fixed it.. It is not my context problem. One of my helper method has async calls, but the method isn't made async..

Comment: @PrzemysławZalewski in the end, that wasn't the issue..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally fixed it. I forgot to make one of my helper method with async calls async and those calls await. So that messed up the whole thing.

Comment: thanks for the answer, sometimes it's not easy to find where "await" is dropped in the code. :)

Comment: you saved by day